# Implement a descending loop in an image?

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am trying to look for 4 white squares in the 4 corners of a binary image. I browse through the first (150x150) corner, and sum up the pixels within a patch of (25x25) pixels. If more than 60% of the patch is white, I convert all of it to black. I implemented it for the top right corner and it's working, here is the code:

```
  while (count1<150)
                {
                   for (int count2 = 0; count2 <150; count2++)

                    {

                        Mat ROI = original.submat(count1, count1 + patch, count2, count2 + patch);
                        int sum = (int) Core.sumElems(ROI).val[0];


                        if (sum > patch * patch * 0.6)

                        {
                            for (int qn1 = count1; qn1 < count1 + patch; qn1++) {
                                for (int qn2 = count2; qn2 < count2 + patch; qn2++)

                                {

                                    original.put(qn1, qn2, 0);

                                }

                            }
                            count1 = 200;
                            break;

                        }

                        else {

                            count1++;

                        }




                    }




                }
```

I'm having trouble implementing it for the other corners though. Here is my code for the bottom right corner, and it doesn't change anything in the image:

```
while (count1<150)                                                                          
{                                                                                           
    for (int count2 = original.width()-1; count2 >original.width()-151; count2--)           

    {                                                                                       

        Mat ROI = original.submat(count1, count1 + patch, count2-patch, count2);            
        int sum = (int) Core.sumElems(ROI).val[0];                                          


        if (sum > patch * patch * 0.6)                                                      

        {                                                                                   
            for (int qn1 = count1; qn1 < count1 + patch; qn1++) {                           
                for (int qn2 = count2-patch; qn2 < count2; qn2++)                           

                {                                                                           

                    original.put(qn1, qn2, 0);                                              

                }                                                                           

            }                                                                               
            count1 = 200;                                                                   
            break;                                                                          

        }                                                                                   

        else {                                                                              

            count1++;                                                                       

        }                                                                                   




    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you made the same mistake I made first time through, you need to reset Count1

```
Count1 = 0;
```

I have not used Java in a very long time, so I translated the code to Igor pro.  Created a 2D array that had patches of the right size in the corners, and passed that into my function.  It also did not set the second patch to zeros, until I put the Count1 = 0 line in.

But I also suspect that you have an off by 1 error in your patch size, if you want the patch to be 4 pixels wide, then you need to subtract 1 when calculating the indexes.  EX: start index is 2, you want 4 pixels including startIndex, you want 2 through 5, Start to Start+Width-1.
But you are consistent with it, so you may be setting patch to 24 if you want a 25 pixel wide patch.

But in general, I would advise 3 things:
Break it down into 2 subfunctions, one to ask the question (and find the index) of the patch, and the other does the action of clearing that patch.  You are going to need to do these things 4 times, once for each corner.  Write the FindPatch function, such that it can find the start index of a patch given a search range.
Then write the clearPatch function to do the work on the image.

Second thing, indexing in difficult.  mistakes are easy, so keep it as simple as possible.  I always index forward if at all possible.  If you think it is really faster to walk backwards through the image, then sure, you need to do it.  I would still recommend returning a start index the same way.  So that ClearPatch can always add Width and Height to a startIndex.  It will simplify that code, so you only have to write and test it once.

Third thing, more of a preference, but the way you are using the outer while loop, could just as well be a for loop.  In fact, if my hunch is right, about needing to reset the Count1, then using a for loop for the outer loop would have solved it before it was ever a problem.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know how I missed that ... Thanks for the recommendations as well, I need it to run backwords, and I didn't use 2 for loops because I needed to break the loop once I find the white patch. However, I realised that instead of browsing the 150x150 patch I am only checking the diagonal line as I am incrementing count1 in the count2 for loop, so I need to fix that too. I'll also try to find a convenient way to do this using a function. Thanks again !